# How Can I show data from 2 different tables using INNER JOIN in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to know what I can do to show data from two different tables using INNER Join in PHP. I use while to recover my database records, but I can't get data from my table "Cliente" and my table "Usuario" simultaneously, I just don't know where I'm missing.... May someone help me to solve it?

Here's the code I use:

```
$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM cliente 
INNER JOIN usuario ON cliente.id_usuario = usuario.id_auto 
WHERE 
usuario.id_imobiliaria = '$id_imobiliaria' 
ORDER BY cliente.id";

$resultado6 = mysql_query($sql6) or die ("Erro na consulta");

$registros1 =  mysql_num_rows($resultado6);

while ($linha6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado6)){
$nome_corretor = $linha6['usuario.id_auto'];
```

Comment: Show tables structure

Comment: use vardump($linha6) to see how column are named. Other solution is not to use * to select all columns but explicit them in the select statement: e.g. SELECT usuario.id_auto as 'auto', usuario.id_imobiliaria as 'imobiliaria' etc. so you can get $linha6['auto'], etc.

Comment: Tks! It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use var_dump($linha6) to see how column are named.

Other solution is not to use `*` to select all columns but *explicit* them in the select statement: e.g. `SELECT usuario.id_auto as 'auto', usuario.id_imobiliaria as 'imobiliaria'` etc. so you can get `$linha6['auto']`, etc.